# ButterKnife sometimes stops working on Android 8.x

Tags: android, butterknife

I have used ButterKnife for 2 years but recently I have had a problem on Android 8. When I am in Activity A, I start Activity B and finish Activity B, then start Activity B and finish Activity B again and again. Sometimes @OnClick in all Activities doesn't work anymore. It is really weird because it just happens in some devices such as Nokia X6 (Android 8.1), Xiaomi Note 5 (Android 8.1) and really hard to reproduce.

```
// This function is not called anymore
@OnClick({R.id.btn1, R.id.btn2})       
public void onViewClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) { 
       // Handle clicks
    }
}
```

Can anyone help? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Vishal The release apk has this issue too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the cause:
In Activity B, I have `mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, 2000)` and if I quickly finish Activity B (< 2000ms), this will cause ButterKnife @OnClick stop working.

So I put `mHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null)` and everything works well!

You can check the issue here: [Issue](https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife/issues/1367)